# Serial Port Returns "\0"

Tags: c#, serial-port

I am trying to communicate with an Industrial weight bridge using a serial port. I know how to write the code code (c#). The problem is when I connect the bridge to the Indicator the weight is displayed. However when I connect the bridge to my PC and run the program all that is returned is "\0"(NULL). When I connect my PC to the indicator and run the program I get continuous "\0". I am using xk3190-a9 indicator. here is sample program

```
namespace SerialPort
{
    class Program
    {
        private static string dev = "";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            System.IO.Ports.SerialPort mySerialPort = new System.IO.Ports.SerialPort("COM15")
            {
                BaudRate = 2400,
                Parity = Parity.None,
                StopBits = StopBits.Two,
                DataBits = 8,
                RtsEnable = true,
            };
            mySerialPort.DataReceived += DataReceivedHandler;
            mySerialPort.Open();
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
            Console.ReadKey();
            mySerialPort.Close();
        }    
        private static void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            System.IO.Ports.SerialPort sp = (System.IO.Ports.SerialPort) sender;
            dev += sp.ReadExisting();
                Console.WriteLine(dev);
        }
    }
}
```

My question is whether the bridge needs "special" commands to send back the weight or what can I do to get the weight. Any other data from the port would be progress. Also I have tried different port settings all same result.

Comment: You shouldn't be asking this question on SO, as most here don't know what weight bridge or indicator are. You have to request this information (it's typically some kind of operation manual) from device support/manufacturer. It could be hardware problem (wrong cable), misconfiguration of communications (e.g. balance can be configured alone to accept wide range of baudrates/parities/etc., you have to **know** how it is currently configured or reconfigure it as you need to) or simply not utilizing communication protocol properly (commands, etc.).

Comment: Along with @Sinatr comments. Most all of your issue lies in not having the serial protocol implemented for whatever the device is. // Another issue you might face is that the Microsoft `SerialPort` implementation is pretty buggy, especially the `DataReceived` event. // Tying both of those answers together the general serial port approach is to `SerialPort.SendBytes` then `SerialPort.ReceiveBytes`. The bytes you send and expect to receive are based on the communication protocol.

Comment: @KDecker I have tried the bytes approach, other than Microsoft's buggy implementation what other lib would you recommend. Sinatr The manual is Chinese and after translation it talks about a software bundled together with the bridge, which requires windows Xp :P which is in Chinese and only does the weighing... I would like to do more than weigh otherwise I would use indicator...

Comment: @LordBlack I use Microsoft's implementation still, if you work around the bugs it works just fine, they are documented pretty well online by others. // Without knowing the serial protocol for the device there is no way you tried "the bytes approach". You must know what to send and receive for it to work.

Comment: You need to implement the ErrorReceived event so you can see errors.  Like the framing errors you might get from not guessing correctly at the number of stopbits or baudrate.  The use of ReadExisting() is also not correct, no guarantee whatsoever that you get the full response of a measurement.  Perhaps ReadLine or ReadTo can do a better job but you'll have to look in the manual for the protocol.  Scales that operate at such low baudrates generally send binary data, the kind that you have to Read() and count-off.  The manual should tell you.

Comment: @KDecker there is a question on SO that had a Spanish protocol for communicating with a bridge, I had tried my luck with those commands like 'W' for weight '# 'for reset etc, it's when I used the "bytes way" I have resorted to contact manufacture I just don't know when I get past sales through to technical though,

Comment: @HansPassant I had implemented all those. No errors at all at any baud rate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching online and not finding a solution that would fit my case I gave up the digital chase and consulted a weight bridge 'specialist'. In case you are pulling out your hair too, here are a few things to note:

1. Most weight bridges(trucks and vehicles) will send the weight as an analogue signal. So even though they have a serial port your computer will definately not "get it" hence the \0 return.
2. To get any weight to your software you will have to go through an indicator which has converters on it's motherboard which read the analogue signal and can convert it to a digital signal
3. As much as indicators get it, some of them have very low BaudRates and the rate might be set at a weird number(see 4) so you might want to try from as low as 100 to 9600. In my case the BaudRate was 600 which I never tried hence the continuous \0
4. Know how to configure your indicator - A simple google search using the indicator number should yield a good English language manual, it might be confusing at first but that is the only way you will be able to change the BaudRate(among other settings) and avoid all the guessing.
5. Simple indicators return GrossWeight and most times this is sufficient but incase you need weight per axle or you want weight on each load cell you might need an advanced indicator like Avery Weigh-Tronix E1310

This notes should guide you to a viable solution, I got mine from 1,3 & 4.

Comment: You know, there is a setting on the `SerialPort` class to ignore any NULL characters coming over the stream. If you are getting a continuous stream of NULL characters, then you might want to turn on this option. The data might be in there somewhere and you're just not seeing it. Also, this sort of sounds like an electrical engineering problem.

Comment: All of your **things to note** should have been posted in the original question.

Comment: man where did you come from, if I had those things to note I would not have asked the question. if you don't like how it is do some editing 